# How do I designate a folder as a Source folder by default in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a somewhat atypical folder structure where my java sources are in 2 different source folder,

```
src/main/java
src/main/some-generated-code
```

IntelliJ does not recognize some-generated-code as a source folder and this obviously leads to all sorts of red-warnings in the IDE.

One way to fix this obviously is to go to the Project explorer right click on some-generated-code and "Mark Directory As Sources". This works fine. However I have multiple projects with the same structure and I was wondering if it is possible to by default have any folder with the structure `src/main/some-generated-code` designated as a "Source" folder.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
-Right click on the project in Intellij
-Click on "Open Module Settings"
-You'll see something like the below image.
-To assign a folder as a source, click on it and then click Sources
```

-[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted. It worked for me. One thing to note is that a previously created folder may not show up in this dialog. I just right-clicked the main project address and clicked "add folder" from the drop-down menu. This made the folder appear, and allowed me to set it as a source.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/74203874/4134215