# Andorid Root package from file in Wizard Template Intellij

Tags: android, templates, wizard, package-name

> Create a file in the application package(top level) using **Intellij Wizard Template**.It's working in some machine and not working in linux machine.

```
fun getApplicationPackageFile(srcOut: File, applicationPackage: String): File {
    var applicationPackageFile = srcOut.path.toString()
    var pk = applicationPackage.replace(".", "\\")

    val status: Boolean = applicationPackageFile.contains(pk)
    return if (status) {
        var file =
            applicationPackageFile.substring(0, applicationPackageFile.indexOf(pk)) + pk + "\\"
        File(file)
    } else {
        srcOut
    }
}
```

I think else part work on linux machine or some machines
My inital structure can look like this

```
main-application-package
  -> package-i-created-myself
     -> Create template here
```

So It should create **common package** under main package along with `AppViewModel` and `AppActivity`

```
main-application-package
  -> common
     -> AppViewModel
     -> AppActivity
  -> package-i-created-myself
     -> Create template here
```

But in some machine it is under package-i-created-myself like

```
my-main-application-package
  
  -> package-i-created-myself
    -> common
       -> AppViewModel
       -> AppActivity
    -> Create template here
```

I am using above code like

```
  val pkFile = getApplicationPackageFile(srcOut, applicationPackage)

  save(
        getStrAppViewModel(applicationPackage),
        pkFile.resolve("common/AppViewModel.$ktOrJavaExt"
      )
        
 save(
        getStrAppClass(applicationPackage),
        pkFile.resolve("common/AppActivity.$ktOrJavaExt")
    )
```

Where srcOut is the directory(package) on click of which I add Template. and applicationPackage is get from

```
moduleData.projectTemplateData.applicationPackage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Create a file in the application package(top level) using Intellij Wizard Template.It's working in some machine and not working in linux machine.

For linux and Mac machines
You only need to change this line of code

```
var pk = applicationPackage.replace(".", "/")
```

**Complete Code**

```
fun getApplicationPackageFile(srcOut: File, applicationPackage: String): File {
    var applicationPackageFile = srcOut.path.toString()
    var pk = applicationPackage.replace(".", "/")

    val status: Boolean = applicationPackageFile.contains(pk)
    return if (status) {
        var file =
            applicationPackageFile.substring(0, applicationPackageFile.indexOf(pk)) + pk 
        File(file)
    } else {
        srcOut
    }
}
```